# ERROR Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly send

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I am getting the following error While trying to transfer fund from one account to another:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly send. Be aware that it might still be mined!
    at /home/munim/codes/eth-test-01/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-core-method/src/index.js:368:45
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:314:12)
    at tryCatcher (/home/munim/codes/eth-test-01/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/munim/codes/eth-test-01/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:497:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/munim/codes/eth-test-01/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:555:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/munim/codes/eth-test-01/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:600:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/munim/codes/eth-test-01/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:679:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/munim/codes/eth-test-01/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:125:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/munim/codes/eth-test-01/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:135:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/munim/codes/eth-test-01/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:16:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)
```

My `genesis.json` file:

```
{
  "config": {
        "chainId": 10,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
  "alloc"      : {},
  "coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty" : "0x20000",
  "extraData"  : "",
  "gasLimit"   : "0x2fefd8",
  "nonce"      : "0x0000000000000042",
  "mixhash"    : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp"  : "0x00"
}
```

Initiated **geth** with the following command:

```
~ geth --datadir="./prinet-betty/data/" init prinet-betty/genesis.json
~ eth --fast --cache=1024 --rpc --rpcaddr="localhost" --rpccorsdomain="*" --datadir="./prinet-betty/data" --nodiscover --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal" console
```

The following code returns the error

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

web3.eth.getAccounts((err, acc) => {
    console.log(acc);
    web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(acc[0], "qwer1234", 1500)
    .then(res => {
        if (res === true) {
            web3.eth.sendTransaction({
                from: acc[0],
                to: acc[1],
                value: web3.utils.toWei(0.1, "ether")
            })
            .then(console.log)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: One possible cause is the difficulty in your genesis is too high try lowering to "0x400" or below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running this process, you will start before 5 min because it will increase the speed of mining process.
To start mining run:-

miner.start() before compiling node js where api are created.

Answer (score 1):

One source of this obscure error is if the signing key belongs to the receiver! The api does not detect if the implicit private key's address differs from the 'sender' field!